# Using enctype="multipart/form-data" ends with csrf error

Tags: node.js, forms, csrf, multer

I am using multer and csurf package.
What is problem is that when i add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form i get invalid csrd token.

app.js

```
// CSRF BEFORE ROUTES!!!
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});

// Routes
app.use("/", webRoutes);
app.use("/cms", cmsRoutes);
```

and part of my users route which is inside my cmsRoutes

```
router.post("/edit", isAuthenticated, upload.single('avatar'), profile.user_edit_profile);
```

I found other people having the same problem. But cant find any solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Just needed to put MULTER BEFORE CSRF.